# Canvas size affected by jQuery slide toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, canvasjs

I have a CanvasJs chart and the dimension is fine. I decided to add a link to show or hide the chart and now the chart is shrank in width. When I resize the browser window by dragging the window handles it changes to the  width it's suppose to have.

HTML:

```
<p> 
       <a href="javascript: showTests();">See chart</a>

</p>

 <section id="charts_wrapper">


 </section>
```

CSS:

```
 #charts_wrapper{
    display: none;
}

.chartContainer{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

JS that generates the chart:

```
 window.onload = function () {
    var grades = <?php echo json_encode($grades);?>;
    if("" != grades){
        var  chartObject1 = {

              title:{

              text: ""              
         },

         axisY: {
           prefix: "",
           suffix: "%",
           minimum: 0,
           maximum: 100,
           interval: 5,
           title: "Notas"
       },
       axisX: {

            title: "Subjects"
       },
         data: [            
           { 

            type: "bar",

            toolTipContent: "{label}: {y}%",
            dataPoints: []
          }
          ]

        };

           for(var key in grades) {
                   var value = grades[key];

                   var obj = {};
                   obj.label = key;
                   obj.y = parseInt(value);

                   chartObject1['data'][0]['dataPoints'].push(obj);


        }


        var chartdiv = '<div class="chartContainer" id="chartContainer1"></div>';


         $('#charts_wrapper').append(chartdiv);

         var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", chartObject1);
         chart1.render();

    }
```

}

JS display div:

```
 function showTests(){
     $('#charts_wrapper').slideToggle();

 }
```

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle or something where we can play with the active code? Your example is difficult because we don't have the data to create the chart.

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue with a simplified fiddle, but I am not seeing the size issues : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywvm5h9t/) -- sorry

Comment: I dont know it must be a bug in the CanvasJS.Chart or something :( Anyways I gave up on hiding the display.

Answer (score 0):

You could try triggering the resize event in jQuery after your slide toggle completes?

```
function showTests(){
    $('#charts_wrapper').slideToggle();
    $(window).trigger('resize');   //trigger resize event from javascript
}
```